# About Ubuntu Cloud servers requirement?

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

I'm researching about Ubuntu Cloud. Could you please let me ask something? Thanks in advance :)

1. Why Ubuntu says that Cloud requires 5 servers, but Juju just requires 4 servers?
2. For Ubuntu Cloud, if we have 5 servers, which services are installed on each node?
3. Ubuntu says it requires 2 node with 2 NICs. I understand the first is Neutron node, so what is the second node?
4. I cannot find any information about the minimum hardware requirement for each node to install Ubuntu Cloud. Can you tell me that?

Hoang